# Getting Fatal error, while trying to parse html with simple html dom parser PHP

Tags: php, parsing, dom, attributes

I am trying to get comments and additional information from website. I can get all comments from first page, but I want to parse all comment pages and get every single comment, its author and time when its posted. For first page code works, it also finds the correct url for the next page, but when it tries to parse next page I get this error: **Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:.../simple_html_dom.php on line 1113**.

How to fix this and parse all the pages?

```
$url = "http://apollo.tvnet.lv/komentari/zinas/687521/1";

$nextLink = $url;    

while ($nextLink) {
   echo "<hr>nextLink: $nextLink<br>";
   //Create a DOM object
   $html = new simple_html_dom();
   // Load HTML from a url
   $html->load_file($nextLink);

$articles = $html->find('div [class=article-comment]');

foreach($articles as $article) {

    $content = $article->find('div[class=article-comment-content]',0)->innertext;

    $author = $article->find('strong[class=article-comment-author]',0)->innertext;

    $date = $article->find('time[class=article-comment-date]',0)->innertext;


    printf("AUTHOR: %s </br> CONTENT: %s </br> Time: %s </br>", $author, $content, $date);

  $nextLink = ( ($temp = $html->find(' a[class=pageing-button-next]', 0)) ? "http://apollo.tvnet.lv".$temp->href : NULL );

// Clear DOM object
$html->clear();
unset($html);
```

}

Comment: Looks like either the file you want to load is not accessible or is not valid html.

Comment: It is a valid HTML and file definetly is accessible

Comment: Have you tried to var_dump `$html` after calling `load_file` ?

Comment: var_dump did not help :(

Comment: $html->clear();
unset($html):

this sets $html to null after page has been parsed

Comment: $html=file_get_html($nextLink);   this solved my problem